# How to create a list that groups columns according to their type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains over 200 columns.
I need to create two lists that group columns by type.
Rather than creating this list manually I tried different methods that did not work:

```
numeric_transformer = df.dtypes == 'int64'
```

or:

```
numeric_transformer = df.apply(lambda x: x if df.dtypes == 'int64' or 'float64' else 
None, axis=1)
```

or :

```
categorical_transformer = df.apply(lambda x: x if df[df.dtypes == 'object'] else None, 
axis=1)
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input **as dataframe constructor** (`df = pd.DafaFrame(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that for this question you can use [df.select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) like this :

```py
numeric_transformer = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns #exclude object types

categorical_transfomer = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
```

Another way to do this would be using the list comprehension :

```py
numeric_transformer = [column for column in df.columns if (df.dtypes[column] == 'float') or (df.dtypes[column] == 'int')]

categorical_transformer = [column for column in df.columns if df.dtypes[column] == 'object']
```